# 'Can't set headers after they are sent to the client' NodeJS error when iOS Swift app is sent to the background

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, swiftui

I have an app with Swift/SwiftUI. I use the `ObservableObject` and `JSONDecoder` to get values from my Node.JS Express API to show within my app:

```
struct DevicesList: Decodable {
    var data: [PhilipsHueDevicesListEntry]
}

struct DevicesListEntry: Decodable {
    var ID: String
    var Name: String
    var State: Bool
    var Reachable: Bool
}
```

Class that gets the values from the API and puts into the above object:

```
class GetDevices: ObservableObject {

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<GetDevices, Never>()

var DevicesList = DevicesList(data: []){
    didSet {
        didChange.send(self)
    }
}

init(){
    let keychain = KeychainSwift()
    let authToken = keychain.get("authToken")!
    let bridgeID = keychain.get("hubID")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: GlobalVariables.HUEGetDevices)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    let headers = [
        "auth-token": authToken,
        "bridgeID": bridgeID,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"]
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let devices = try! JSONDecoder().decode(DevicesList.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.DevicesList = devices
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Then to show within my Main screen of my app:

```
@State var devices = GetDevices()

ForEach(devices.DevicesList.data, id: \.ID) { device in
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle()
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text(device.Name)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            }
                        }
....
```

Everything works perfectly well, until I swipe up to send the app to the background (which I assume runs the `init()` function again to update the observableObject). I get this error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:503
throw new errors.Error('ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT', 'set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/app-c/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/app-c/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/app-c/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/app-c/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at lightDataCallbackFunction (/app-c/app.js:185:32). // <----- This is where the error occurs in my js file
    at Socket.socket.on (/app-c/app.js:121:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at /app-c/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:176:11)
```

My JS file to which the error occurs:

```
lightDataCallbackFunction = function(data){
    if(data['socketID'] == socketID){
      if(data['code'] == '208'){
        return res.status(200).send(data) // <--- OCCURS HERE
      }else{
        return res.status(400).send({"data": "", "code": "209", "message": data['message']})
      }
    }
  }
```

I genuinely have no idea why this is the case and what is happening. My best guess would be that when I send the app to the background, the observable object instance is ran again and somehow the same server-side code tries to send another (same) response to my app? I even return the response to exit the function, so I do not see why this is happening?

EDIT:

I have tried MwcsMac comment from below, he mentioned that he usually just doesn't use the `init()` function at all, instead he moves the code that would go inside the `init()` function and puts it inside a new function, then calls that function when the view in question loads via `.onAppear()`.

I have tried that, however it either doesn't run the function at all for whatever reason - or it just doesn't update my view (populating my `ForEach` loop within my SwiftUI code.

Comment: I avoid placing code in the `init(){ }` for reasons just like this.  I place the code you have in the `init` into a function and call that function from the view that needs it.

Comment: @MwcsMac Surely it would just call that function every time the app goes in the background too, changing nothing?

Comment: @MwcsMac I've tried your method, still crashes when I go home, if I call the function again within the view that I need, it just crashes the app immediately

Comment: Did you try having the function trigger only in `.onapper { }` ?

Comment: @MwcsMac Yeah, I removed the `init()` function, made a new function and called that function within the `onAppear()` of my view, nothing happened, the function doesn't even run for some reason and I know the `onAppear()` is working as I put a print statement in it to test??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI has `@Observedobject` wrapper as explicit design pair of `ObservableObject`, so let's use this pattern.

1. Make GetDevices use standard publishing approach

```
class GetDevices: ObservableObject {

  @Published var DevicesList = DevicesList(data: [])

  private var isIdle = true
  func load() {
    guard isIdle else { return }
    isIdle = false

    let keychain = KeychainSwift()
    let authToken = keychain.get("authToken")!
    let bridgeID = keychain.get("hubID")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: GlobalVariables.HUEGetDevices)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    let headers = [
        "auth-token": authToken,
        "bridgeID": bridgeID,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"]
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let devices = try! JSONDecoder().decode(DevicesList.self, from: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.DevicesList = devices
            self.isIdle = true
        }
    }.resume()
  }
}
```

2. Use ObservedObject/ObservableObject in View

```
 @ObservedObject var devices = GetDevices()
 //@StateObject var devices = GetDevices()   // << use this for SwiftUI2.0 / iOS14+

 var body: some View {

   List {  // << some top container View

        // ... your dynamic content here

    }
    .onAppear {
       self.devices.load()      // << call here !!
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked! But how? I don't understand what was wrong? Could you explain why and how and I can award the bounty to you. Also, Since inside the list there is a button I press to change the state, how would I invoke that `load()` function when I change state, e.g. force the view to update whenever the user presses the button? I've tried calling the `load()` function whenever the button is pressed, however the view only updates the second time I press it?

Comment: `ObservableObject-ObservedObject` is correct intended documented pattern, but `ObservableObject-State` is not. If, about button, you mean complete reset, then you can just create new instance `self.devices = GetDevices()` and call `self.devices.load()` again in button action, or add reset function inside `GetDevices` class which would cleanup data array and call load again... or your own variant.